# Using cypher to get set amount of top results

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph which has states following each other in time. Each of the states can have a number of actions that happened (0..n) and a number of recommendations (0..n) assigned by some software.

I can do a query on cypher like this

```
start n=node:name(name="State")
match a<-[:hasAction]-s-[:isA]->n
s-[l?:hasRecommendation]->r 
where l.likelihood>0.2
return distinct s.name as state, collect(a.name) as actions,
r.name as recommendation, l.likelihood as likelihood
order by s.name asc, l.likelihood desc
```

which gives me a table like this

```
state   | actions    | recommendation | likelihood
--------------------------------------------------
State 1 | [a1,a2,a3] | a1             | 0.25
State 1 | [a1,a2,a3] | a4             | 0.05
State 2 | [a2,a3]    | a3             | 0.56
State 2 | [a2,a3]    | a2             | 0.34
State 2 | [a2,a3]    | a1             | 0.15
```

If I process that table manually, I can filter these results and have only the top 2 results for each state for example. This is time consuming and very unelegant.

My problem is, that I never know how many recommendations a state has, so I can't use limit/skip here. Ideally I'd like it to return only a set amount of states (e.g 100) including their top recommendations - this query could return between 0 and 100*n lines.

Is there a better way to achieve this in cypher?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to achieve this is to select the states that have recommendations and limit the result to 100 first, and then only retrieve the top 2 recommendations for these 100 states by dynamically computing the percentiles for each state, something like this,

```
start n=node:name(name="State")
Match s-[:isA]->n, s-[?:hasRecommendation]->r
With distinct s
Order by s.name
limit 100
Match s-[?:hasRecommendation]->r
With s, (count(r)-1.0) / count(r) as p
Match s-[l?:hasRecommendation]->r
With s, percentile_disc(l.likelihood, p) as m
start n=node:name(name="State")
match a<-[:hasAction]-s-[:isA]->n,
s-[l?:hasRecommendation]->r 
where l.likelihood>= m
return distinct s.name as state, collect(a.name) as actions,
r.name as recommendation, l.likelihood as likelihood
order by s.name asc, l.likelihood desc
```

It's a bit verbose, but Cypher does not support nested functions for aggregations. so I have to get the "count" and the "percentile" with two separate queries.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem in my question. I want to have a maximum amount of (different) recommendations for each state but your query returns all the recommendations there are

Comment: You mean the limit say 100 is set to the number of recommendations for each state instead of total number of states?

Comment: Almost. I mean I would like to get 100 states and each of the states is supposed to have its top 3 recommendations. If there are only 2 (or 1 or even 0 - which in reality never happens), that's fine as well I just want to filter the recommendations. If I do this by likelihood alone, I might get no recommendation because the best one has only a very low likelihood.

Comment: I see. The only way I can think of is to calculate the percentile for each state first in terms of the total count of recommendations and the desired number of results, then use the resulting percentile value as the criteria to filter out those recommendation with a likelihood less than the percentile value.

Comment: I modified my query to use percentile to get top 2 recommendations for each state.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I edited it to get rid of the copy&paste errors so it compiles but it still returns too many recommendations per state.

Comment: I tested the query on the subgraph only consisted of (State)-[:HasRecommendation]->(Action) and it works fine. I can't see where the problem is. Would you care to create a sample graph on neo4j console http://console.neo4j.org/, so that we can play and see where the problem is?

Comment: I can't do this as it's sensitive data I'm working with. My graph has about 3k nodes, >70k properties and >80k relationships and if I run your query it returns the same data that the query in my question does.

Comment: After having looked at it again, I found that the reason WHY your query is failing is that if there are say 3 recommendations that have the same likelihood (which happens quite often), it will return all of them instead of only 2 random ones (like order/limit would do).

Comment: Oh, I see, I didn't test this case. You are right, it filters on the values rather than the number of records.